# Killing and reaping process

Tags: c, unix, posix

I have a child process specified by `pid`. This process could be:

1. Running
2. Defunct/Zombie (unreaped)
3. Already reaped (and thus no longer exists)

I would like to kill this process and ensure no zombie remains. Currently my code is

```
kill(pid, SIGKILL);
int temp;
waitpid(pid, &temp, 0);
```

Would this work?

EDIT: The process specified by `pid` is a child of my program.

Comment: You should probably think about the possibility that the `pid` has already been reused for a different process.

Comment: That's a good point aix. Might it be a good idea to first check if the process is a child of my program?

Comment: @Sticky: No need to check for that, since if the pid is not a child waitpid() will fail and set errno to ECHILD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine so far, but I wonder why you would let case 3 happen. You should perform some bookkeeping, which of your child processes have terminated and are waiting to be reaped.
One way would be to install a handler for `SIGCHLD`, setting a flag that a `waitpid` is in order. That way you guarantee that all pids are actually those of your child processes.

Answer (score 2):

Should work fine, but be sure to check the returnvalue of waitpid.
The call may have returned due to a signal.